# how to use apache date utils to find number of days difference between two dates

Tags: java, apache

I would like to know to create a method to calculate the difference between two dates in days
 and Number of hours and minutes between the two Date times.

Comment: Could you please tell us what have you tried so far?

Comment: You can find answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165564/calculating-days-between-two-dates-with-in-java