# how to calculate the difference between 2 dates in java?

Tags: java, date

how to calculate the difference between 2 dates used in a string format(dd/mm/yyyy) and returns the value as the number of days between the 2 dates

```
    DatePickerDialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(TastSchedulingMainActivity.this,new OnDateSetListener() {    
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int y, int m,int d) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                enddate.setText(d+"/"+ (m+1) +"/"+ y);
                }
            } , year, month, day);      
            picker.show();
        }
```

Comment: Did you check [Similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165564/calculating-days-between-two-dates-with-in-java)

Comment: thanks singhakash sorry for asking previously asked question >>

Comment: In the future you'll want to search the site for similar questions before asking.