# Subtract Date; Date format

Tags: java

I've two following dates

String d1 = "Fri May 11 01:48:50 +0000 2015";

String d2 = "Thu May 10 20:49:20 +0000 2015";

long result = 0;

I want to subtract d2 from d1. But, I don't know how to format d1 and d2(SimpleDateFormat or something else) for subtraction. Could someone help me?

Comment: You have to get milisecond from date and substract long values.

Comment: And a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30761682/642706) and many more. Search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8+, you can get the [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) between two `Date`(s) with something like

```
String d1 = "Fri May 11 01:48:50 +0000 2015";
String d2 = "Thu May 10 20:49:20 +0000 2015";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
try {
    Date a = df.parse(d1);
    Date b = df.parse(d2);
    Duration d = Duration.between(a.toInstant(), b.toInstant());
    System.out.println(d);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs

```
PT-4H-59M-30S
```

For 4 hours, 59 minutes and 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, it's works. :)