# Is there a way to get the days as a result of arrays if we pass two dates into a function in java

Tags: java, android, date

### How to get different days between two dates in java:

**Source Date**: `01-09-2015`

**Destination Date**: `03-09-2015`
.

***So there are three days:*** `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`, `Thursday` but does not include 
`Monday`, `Friday`, `Saturday`, `Sunday`

---

**Question**:

1. Is there a way to get the days as a result of arrays if we pass two
   dates into a function in java
2. Also trying not to have duplicate values(Monday-Sunday)

Comment: The technical term is a *[distinct](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinct) list* of day-of-week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), you can do like this :

```
public ArrayList<String> getDaysBetween(String start, String end){
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    DateTime dstart = formatter.parseDateTime(start);
    DateTime dend = formatter.parseDateTime(end);

    ArrayList<String> days = new ArrayList<>();
    while (dstart.getDayOfYear() <= dend.getDayOfYear()){
        String day = dstart.dayOfWeek().getAsText();
        if(!days.contains(day)){
            days.add(day);
        }
        dstart = dstart.plusDays(1);
    }
    return days;
}
```

It works when the two dates are on the same year.

Moreover:

```
dstart.dayOfWeek().getAsText();
```

return a String based on the current local (in French : "mardi", "mercredi"... - in English : "tuesday", "wednesday"...).

Answer (score 1):

I have quickly compiled the following program in Java which may serve your purpose.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String inputString1 = "01-09-2015";
        String inputString2 = "10-09-2015";
        Date date1 = myFormat.parse(inputString1);
        Date date2 = myFormat.parse(inputString2);
        long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(date1);


        int days = (int) TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        days = Math.min(days,7);
        String[] resultArray = new String[days];
        for(int i=0; i< days; i++) {
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            String result = new SimpleDateFormat("EE").format(c.getTime());
            resultArray[i] = result;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultArray));
        }
```

It prints:

`[Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue]`

Comment: You can optimize it by    for(int i=0; i<Math.min(days, 7); i++)

Comment: @ akhil_mittal ........ Code is working but its one day less and there are duplicates

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165564/calculating-days-between-two-dates-with-in-java looks familiar. @Devrath use Alexandrs loop condition to avoid dupes

Comment: @ dly ... though i use alexander loop condition ... still there are duplicates

Comment: @Alexandr: Thanks for suggeation

Comment: @Devrath: Duplicates in what sense?

Comment: @akhil_mittal OP wants every weekday once. So if there are two mondays in the time span put only one into the result array.

Comment: @Devrath: Can you please check edited code once? Is this what you want?