# Is the TimeUnit class broken?

Tags: java, date, calendar, milliseconds, timeunit

I noticed a strange behaviour of the TimeUnit class, so I created this minimal example to reproduce it.

```
long differenceInDays;

Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();

c1.setTimeInMillis(1466062306000l); // Thu Jun 16 2016 09:31:46 GMT+0200
c2.setTimeInMillis(1466028000000l); // Thu Jun 16 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200

differenceInDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(c2.getTimeInMillis() - c1.getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
System.out.println(differenceInDays); // obviously zero

c2.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
differenceInDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(c2.getTimeInMillis() - c1.getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
System.out.println(differenceInDays); // why zero and not one?

c2.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
differenceInDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(c2.getTimeInMillis() - c1.getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
System.out.println(differenceInDays); // suddenly a 1, but not a 2 like expected
```

It is obvious that the first time the difference is calculated it is 0, because not a whole day lies between the dates.

But the second time a whole day is added, so how can the difference be still 0?

Output:

> 0
> 0
> 1

I don't think this problem is daylight saving time or leap year related because I only do calculations within the same year, even month.

[Here](http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/#.V2MbqvmLSUk) is a date to milliseconds calculator for you to check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see better what's going on here with simple math:

```
c1 = 1466062306000
c2 = 1466028000000

d = 86400000                // one day

c2 - c1 = -34306000         // negative, but less than one day in magnitude
c2 - c1 + d = 52094000      // less than one day
c2 - c1 + d + d = 138494000 // more than one day, less than two days
```

The *correct* way to handle this, assuming you're using Java 8, is as follows:

```
// Decide what time zone you want to work in
ZoneId tz = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");

// If you wanted the local time zone of the system,
// Use this instead:
// ZoneId tz = ZoneId.systemDefault();

// Get instants from the timestamps
Instant i1 = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1466062306000l);
Instant i2 = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1466028000000l);

// Get the calendar date in the specified time zone for each value
LocalDate d1 = i1.atZone(tz).toLocalDate();
LocalDate d2 = i2.atZone(tz).toLocalDate();

// Get the difference in days
long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d2, d1);
```

If your inputs are truly `Calendar` objects instead of timestamps, I'd suggest `Calendar.toInstant()` as described in the [Legacy Date-Time Code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/legacy.html) guidance.

If you're using Java 7 or earlier, you will find similar capabilities from the [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

if you really don't want to use any of these, and still do things the old (hard) way, then see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28865648/634824).