# Get count day between to date Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, chronounit

Hello i need to get count day between to date using ChronoUnit

this is my code :

```
            Date madate = rfxobjet.getRv_rc_date();
            Date date=java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            Date res=null;
            int day = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(madate,date);
```

but i got this error :
The method between(Temporal, Temporal) in the type ChronoUnit is not applicable for the arguments (Date, Date)

please what i should to do i need to resolve this error

Comment: Use one of the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) types instead of `Date`.

Comment: Never use the legacy classes `Date` or `Calendar`. Use only classes from the *java.time* packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating days between two dates with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165564/calculating-days-between-two-dates-with-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix different API.
Date is an old class which was in Java since JDK 1.
While ChronoUnit is from newer date API appeared first from JDK8.
Normally you should use newer API. It means that instead of Date you should use LocalDate (or LocalDateTime) which is part of the new API.

So in order to correct your code you need to make so that madate and date are both instances of LocalDate.
E.g. this should work:

```
LocalDate madate = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
long day = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(madate, date);
```

Or if you need still need to use Date objects you can convert them to Temporal objects:

```
Date madate = rfxobjet.getRv_rc_date();
Date date = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
long day = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(madate.toInstant(), date.toInstant());
```

Temporal is a base class for LocalDate and LocalDateTime so using Date.toInstant() you essentially convert date to corresponding instance in new API.

NB. between() returns long so the day variable also needs to be of type long or you need to use to int conversion:

```
int day = (int) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(madate, date);
```

Comment: Almost correct. `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(madate.toInstant(), date.toInstant());` counts a day as always 24 hours. A day is not always 24 hours, so you may get a date too many or too few occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

```java
Date madate = rfxobjet.getRv_rc_date();//please consider renaming this variable
LocalDate madataLocalDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(madate.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
long day = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(madataLocalDate, now);
```

Basically you need to use classes from the `java.time` package, you can't mix between `java.util.Date` and `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: @OleV.V. hmm, weird. I've edited it so both dates are `LocalDate` see if that works.

Comment: It works now, thank you. I don’t find it that weird. From the documentation of `between()`: *The implementation will convert the second type to be an instance of the first type before the calculating the amount.* We cannot convert a `LocalDate` to `LocalDateTime` since we don’t know the time of day (the opposite conversion goes well).

Answer (score 1):

You should stop using the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

If `rfxobjet.getRv_rc_date()` returns an object of `java.util.Date`, your first step should be to convert it into an object of type, [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) by calling [Date#toInstant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--) on this object i.e.

```
Date madate = rfxobjet.getRv_rc_date();
Instant instant = madate.toInstant();
```

Once you have an object of `Instant`, you can convert it to any other modern date-time object as per your requirement e.g.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.now();
        // I've used the time-zone of Europe/London as an example, you can choose any
        // time-zone as per your requirement. You can also select the time-zone used by
        // your JVM, ZoneId.systemDefault()
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
        OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime();
        LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(instant);
        System.out.println(zdt);
        System.out.println(odt);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-06-28T16:58:27.725618Z
2020-06-28T17:58:27.725618+01:00[Europe/London]
2020-06-28T17:58:27.725618+01:00
2020-06-28T17:58:27.725618
```

**Note:** `LocalDateTime` drops off information like **Zone Offset** and **Zone ID** which may be required in your business logic. Therefore, choose the appropriate class as per the table shown below ([Ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html)):
[image]

## Back to your problem:

Now that you have an object of `Instant`, you can get an instance of `LocalDateTime` as described above i.e.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
```

The final step is to get the number of days between now and `ldt` which you can do as follows:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(ldt, now);
```

Note that I've passed `ZoneId` as the parameter to `LocalDateTime.now` just as the recommended practice so that you can specify the required `ZoneId` as per your requirement. If you do not pass this parameter, it will use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` by default.

**The complete code:**

```
Date madate = rfxobjet.getRv_rc_date();
Instant instant = madate.toInstant();
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(ldt, now);
```